# How to speed up sensitivity analysis?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got to deal with a sensitivity analysis that needs speed up. Data is given in a numpy array let's call it `A`. `A` got shape `(M, N)` where `M` is the number of data points and `N` is the number of attributes each data point consists of and on which the analysis shall be computed. For simplicity let's assume `M=2, N=4`. Have something like `M=1+e9` in mind. Anyway. Let `a_{mn}` be an element of `A`. Analysis should be done for function `f(a_{m1},a_{m2}, a_{m3}, a_{m4}) = a_{m1} - a_{m2} - ( a_{m3} * a_{m4} )` computing for each row, so that `f(A)` leads to array `B` shape `(M,1)`. So `b_m` is an element of `B`.

Want to create array `E` shape `(M, N)` containing the sensitivity for every element on `B` in total. e.g. element `e: m=1 an n=2, e_{mn}= e_{12} = f(a_{11},a_{12}*(1-i), a_{13}, a_{14}) - b_1`

Now searching for each elements sensitivity on `B`. Let the sensitivity `i` be `i=0.05`. First of all I computed an array of shape `(M, N)` that contains all elements and its change. Let's call that `C = B * i`, where `*` is an element-wise multiplication. After that, creating `D`, I looped over every single element in the array. Finally subtracted `B` to get `E`. That is too expensive and very cheesy, I guess. That's why it doesn't work with a huge amount of data. Here is what I got:

```py
import numpy as np

A = np.array([
    [2., 2., 100., 0.02],
    [4., 2., 100., 0.02]
])

def f_from_array(data):
    att_1 = data[:, 0]
    att_2 = data[:, 1]
    att_3 = data[:, 2]
    att_4 = data[:, 3]
    return ((att_1 - att_2) - (att_3 * att_4)).reshape(-1, 1)

def f_from_list(data):
    att_1 = data[0]
    att_2 = data[1]
    att_3 = data[2]
    att_4 = data[3]
    return ((att_1 - att_2) - (att_3 * att_4)).reshape(-1, 1)

B = f_from_array(A)

# B = np.array([
#     [-2.],
#     [0.]
# ])

i = 0.05
C = A * i
A_copy = A * 1
D = np.zeros(A.shape)
for m in range(A.shape[0]):
    for n in range(A.shape[1]):
        A_copy[m][n] -= C[m][n]
        D[m][n] = f_from_list(A_copy[m])
        A_copy = A * 1

E = D - B
E = np.sqrt(E**2)
```

Output:

```py
E = np.array([
    [0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1],
    [0.2, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
])
```

Comment: `$A$` Why are you using this notation?

Comment: LaTeX notation - wondering stackoverlow can't handle that. Will delete those $ [link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76902/how-can-i-write-math-formula-in-a-post)

Comment: The notation and therefore the description of what you intent to compute is pretty hard to read for someone who only knows Python, but no LaTeX. It might be beneficial to format it with Python/Numpy syntax instead.

Comment: Fair point. There for I added runing code, wich your answer below speeded up a bit. Thanks for that, but as you mentioned that loops could be eliminated completely. How to do this?

Comment: Sure, one could go off the code, but it would also be nice to be able to verify whether the code actually does what you want. For instance, I'm not so sure about the last line(s): `np.sqrt(E ** 2)` is basically the same as `np.abs(E)` for real numbers. It's more likely you meant something along the lines of `np.sqrt((E ** 2).mean(axis=0))`, which is the RMS along the columns.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, the problematic part of your code is the nested for loop. There's a lot that can be done here and it's probably possible to eliminate the loop completely.

But without thinking too much about what the code does, the most obvious time killer is probably that you create a copy of the whole array during **every** loop iteration. Eliminate that by just restoring the one element instead of the whole array.

Instead of

```
A_copy = A * 1
```

inside the loop, do this:

```
A_copy[m, n] = A[m, n]
```

(As an aside: Indexing with comma is slightly faster than doing a multiple-step indexing with more than one pair of brackets, but it will probably be insignificant for your case.)